Encrypt and Decrypt in the same python script using Fernet
I am trying to test encryption before sending the encrypted columns in a dataframe to a colleague.
I tried:
load_dotenv()

secret_key = os.getenv('secret_key')

fernet_out = Fernet(secret_key)

def encrypt_data(field_value):            
    try:
        return fernet_out.encrypt(field_value.encode())
    except Exception as e:
        return field_value  

transactions['titre'] = transactions['titre'].apply(encrypt_data)
transactions['titre_origine'] = transactions['titre_origine'].apply(encrypt_data)

The encryption was successful. Here is an example of the output:
                                                    titre  \
0       b'gAAAAABnCRr14wRSZ6GBKk0mC7IVRPJc_ZBBk-6-x1Pz...   
1       b'gAAAAABnCRr1rBUy1XYbd96J2gu_uixDuHiiB3N2ahu_...   
2       b'gAAAAABnCRr16CMlKRFwuU_qWQl_aYCrYrvyZck9xelh...   
3       b'gAAAAABnCRr1AAdNLpy4Nwy70lJrO4f5r7QclFPmKqBa...   
4       b'gAAAAABnCRr1xnOka06WgK4AcXkoj1SlZXRa3fSBTMjF...   
...                                                   ...   
708088  b'gAAAAABnCRs5AELW3LO6WEpERE2LvJGWoettvk6qlSML...  

But immedialtely i tried to decrypt with the same key to make sure my colleague can decrypt. I tried:
secret_key = os.getenv('secret_key')

fernet_out = Fernet(secret_key)

def decrypt_field(field_value):
    
    try:
        return fernet_out.decrypt(field_value.encode()).decode()
    except Exception as e:
        
        return field_value  

The decryption was not successful. I get the same encrypted output.
Why is that? Knowing that I generated the key.
Thank you for your help

If the ciphertext is returned during decryption, you have probably run into the exception according to your code. You should not ignore the exception, but output the exception message.

The encrypted columns were read as strings. I had to make conversion to bites to fix the problem.
import ast
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
def decrypt_field(field_value):
    '''        
    '''
    try:      
        return fernet_out.decrypt(ast.literal_eval(field_value)).decode()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)  
        return field_value   


print(df['column'].apply(decrypt_field))

The output is what it should be.
